# Can we intelligently control evaluation in Thread?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, function-construction, evaluation, expression-manipulation

This is a bid at creating a canonical Q&A.

Many questions have been asked that come down to the fact that [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) evaluates its first argument before threading is attempted.  In a few minutes I found:

- [Threading behavior of SameQ vs Equals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4390/121)
- [Implementing myMapThread with Thread, Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8360/121)
- [Threading over a list of lists of lists and a list of atomic expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14121/121)
- [Why does Thread FileDate give an error message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37274/121)
- [Efficient calculation of diagonal matrix elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45240/121)
- [List operation list1 >= list2 should compare elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83236/121)
- [How to Thread with custom functions? Thread vs Map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85279/121)
- [Why doesn't Thread always thread?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102104/121)
- [Map works but Thread doesn't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108529/121)
- [Function of Five Variables, and iterating over the last 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133028/121/#134188)
- [Thread Part ([[]]) over two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135909/121)
- [Inconsistent behavior of thread on empty llists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137227/121)

Basic examples of the problem:

```
Thread[{1, 2, 3} == {3, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

(One might have expected `{False, True, False}`)

```
Thread[Print[{a, b, c}, " = ", {1, 2, 3}]];
```

> {a,b,c} = {1,2,3}

(One might have expected `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=3`, on three separate lines.)

**How can this most *easily* and *robustly* be addressed?**

Answer (score 24):

### Analysis of the problem

All functions in *Mathematica* either hold one or more of their arguments, or per [The Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html) the arguments are evaluated before the function is applied.  [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) has no [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) [attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html) therefore it falls into the latter category.

Because of this in an expression like `Thread[Print[{a, b, c}, " = ", {1, 2, 3}]];` `Print` evaluates entirely free of `Thread`, and `Thread` only sees the result of that which is [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null.html).

### Manual evaluation control

The typical solution to this problem is to manually take control of the evaluation order.  A common recommendation is [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) as the head to be applied is kept separate from the expression elements until construction is complete:

```
MapThread[Equal, {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}}]
```

This is hardly a complete solution however as `MapThread` only operates over `List` and does not handle singletons.

Sometimes one can use `Thread` and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) a head afterward, which handles singletons:

```
Print @@@ Thread[{{a, b, c}, " = ", {1, 2, 3}}];
```

> a = 1
>
> b = 2
>
> c = 3

One may wonder why `Thread` does not have `HoldFirst` as referenced at the start.  The mechanism of [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) effectively gives us a one-off operation as though that attribute applied:

```
Thread[ Unevaluated[ {1, 2, 3} == {3, 2, 1} ] ]
```

> ```
> {False, True, False}
> ```

This is not a general solution however because it interferes with expected evaluation in other cases:

```
p = {1, 2, 3};
q = {3, 2, 1};
Thread[ Unevaluated[ foo[p, q] ] ]
```

> ```
> foo[{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}]
> ```

More complicated cases may require one to inject various evaluated forms into an `Unevaluated` expression:

```
p = a + b + c;
q = x + y + z;

With[{p = p, q = q},
  Thread[ Unevaluated[p*q*r], Plus]
]
```

> ```
> a r x + b r y + c r z
> ```

## Automated solution

Wouldn't it be nice to have `Thread` just work in most cases without having to resort to manual evaluation control?  I think so, and I am going to try to make it happen.

Here is my initial attempt.  It surely has limitations and I expect more than a couple of bugs, but already I think it is applicable in a wide range of cases.  I hope that with feedback from the community I can continue to refine and extend it.

I will be using a modified form of my `step` function from [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121#1447) with a specific container to differentiate its results from appearances of [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html).

The code in provided at the bottom to avoid interrupting the flow of this long post.

#### Basic examples

```
autoThread[{1, 2, 3} == {3, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
>  {False, True, False}
> ```

```
autoThread[Print[{a, b, c}, " = ", {1, 2, 3}]];
```

> a = 1
>
> b = 2
>
> c = 3

```
p = {1, 2, 3};
q = {3, 2, 1};
autoThread[foo[p, q]]
```

> ```
> {foo[1, 3], foo[2, 2], foo[3, 1]}
> ```

```
p = a + b + c;
q = x + y + z;
autoThread[p*q*r, Plus]
```

> ```
> a r x + b r y + c r z
> ```

#### Advanced stepwise evaluation

By leveraging the special evaluation provided by `step` my function can do things that are almost impossible otherwise.

```
x := 1 + 2 + 3;
y := a + b + c

autoThread[x*y, Plus]
```

> ```
> a + 2 b + 3 c
> ```

```
foo[6] := x*y
bar := foo;

autoThread[bar[2*3], Plus]
```

> ```
> a + 2 b + 3 c
> ```

#### `autoThread` Code

```
SetAttributes[{step, $stepHold}, HoldAll]
step[expr_] :=
  Module[{P},
    P = (P = Return[$stepHold @@ #, TraceScan] &) &;
    TraceScan[P, expr, TraceDepth -> 1]
  ]

Attributes[autoThread] = HoldFirst;

autoThread[body_] := autoThread[body, List]

autoThread[body : _[___, h_[___], ___], h_, seq_: All] := 
  Thread[Unevaluated @ body, h, seq]

autoThread[body : f_[arg___], h_, seq_: All] :=
  With[{new = 
    Replace[
      MapAll[step, Unevaluated[body], Heads -> True],
      (step | $stepHold)[x_] :> x, -1, Heads -> True
    ]},
   (new /. $stepHold[eval_] :> autoThread[eval, h, seq])
      /; new =!= $stepHold[body]
  ]

autoThread[else_, x___] :=
  step[else] /. $stepHold[eval_] :> autoThread[eval, x]
```

Comment: How would one use `autoThread` on this problem: I wanted to divide both sides of equation by something. Here is an example of what I do now `ClearAll[y, x, s];eq = y''[x] + y'[x] == y[x];ode = eq /. y -> Function[{x}, Exp[s[x]]]` Now I want to divide both sides by `Exp[s[x]]` to cancel that common term out. Currently I do `Simplify@Thread[ode/Exp[s[x]], Equal]`. I tried `autoThread` like this `Simplify[autoThread[ode/Exp[s[x]]]]` and few other ways, but not sure how to use it :)  When I do `Simplify[autoThread[ode/Exp[s[x]]],Equal]` it does not give same result as the `Thread` command.

Comment: @Nasser `SameQ[ Simplify@Thread[ode/Exp[s[x]], Equal], Simplify @ autoThread[ode/Exp[s[x]], Equal] ]` is `True`.  Obviously my code does not simplify things here but it also does not fail.  You must of course still specify `Equal` as the second parameter of `autoThread` or there is no hope for it to guess which head to thread over in the more general picture.

Answer (score 18):

First, let me tell you that my answer here is by no means a replacement for the trickier, but more capable implementation of Mr. Wizard. What I want to show is that the examples I point out at the end can be handled with a shorter approach. Keep this in mind. For a new user of Mathematica, the implementation below might serve as a starting point in understanding, why we need evaluation control for this kind of problem.

The following solution works by temporarily replacing the head, the outermost function, of a given expression with some dummy function that does nothing. Since the dummy function does nothing, `Thread` can do its work and afterward, we simply re-substitute the original head.

As Kuba pointed out, in some cases, it might be a good idea to give the dummy function the same attributes as the original head. I will give an example when this is a good idea.

```
SetAttributes[myThread, {HoldAllComplete}];
myThread[head_[args__]] := Module[{dummy},
  SetAttributes[dummy, Attributes[head]];
  Thread[dummy[args]] /. dummy :> head
]
```

Here are the examples that give the desired output:

```
myThread[{1, 2, 3} == {3, 2, 1}]
(* {False, True, False} *)
```

and

```
myThread[Print[{a,b,c}," = ",{1,2,3}]];
(*
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
*)
```

and

```
lst1 = {{5, -9, 15}, {12, -15, 4}};
indices = {{2, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 2}};

myThread[Part[lst1, indices]]     
(* {{-9, 5, 15}, {12, 4, -15}} *)
```

and

```
myThread@D[{x, y}, {x, y}]
(* {1, 1} *)
```

and

```
findPrime[n_] := 
  If[PrimeQ[n], i = 1; While[Prime[i] < n, i = i + 1]; i, False];

myThread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]
(* {4, False, 12, 31} *)
```

and

```
myThread[{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7}~Max~{1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}]
(* {2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 8, 8} *)
```

and finally

```
appendTo[ll_, item_] := Map[Append[#, item] &, ll];
myThread[appendTo[list1, list2]]
(* {{{1, 2, "a"}, {3, 4, 5, "a"}}, {{1, 3, 5, "b"}, {9, 8, 
   "b"}}} *)
```

I left out the "C:.." example because there is no such thing on my machine but it should work as well. One example where we need to give `dummy` the original attributes of the head is this

```
myThread[{1, 2, 3} :> {Print[1], Print[2], Print[3]}]
(* {1 :> Print[1], 2 :> Print[2], 3 :> Print[3]} *)
```

If we don't do this, the `Print` statements would be evaluated and we would be left with

```
{1:>Null,2:>Null,3:>Null}
```

which is not wanted.

Comment: Consider adding: `Attributes[h] = Attributes[head]` in order to not leak evaluation from e.g. `autoThread[{1, 2, 3} :> {Print[1], Print[2], Print[3]}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sorry, I haven't read through all linked posts and didn't look at the bottom of your implementation because I wanted to think about it without seeing your solution. I would have seen the `Thread[expr,head]` examples otherwise. I particularly looked through your example post and thought a simpler solution for them can probably be grasped easier than your involved solution. One problem with `Block` is that you cannot block some basic symbols like `List`, `Plus`, ... which is why I chose the `Module` approach. I will point this out and change my post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't want to challenge your full solution, and specifically, I didn't want that you have to defend the solution you have thought so deeply about.

Comment: @Kuba Good point. I'll include this.

Comment: Forgive me for getting defensive.  Good point regarding `Module` rather than `Block` as well.  I got the feeling you were saying this code would/should replace mine, but I see that is not the case.

Comment: @Kuba I wonder if `Listable` should be applied to `h` if it exists on `head`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Interesting question, I'm not sure but I would probably say yes.

Answer (score 12):

### Specific solutions

Since my goal is for not only this Question to become canonical but also my solution my function must be applicable to *most* cases that come up.

- [Threading behavior of SameQ vs Equals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4390/121)  -- used as the opening example.
- [Implementing myMapThread with Thread, Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8360/121) -- not applicable
- [Threading over a list of lists of lists and a list of atomic expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14121/121) -- success

  ```
  autoThread[appendTo[list1, list2]]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{{1, 2, "a"}, {3, 4, 5, "a"}}, {{1, 3, 5, "b"}, {9, 8, "b"}}}
  > ```
- [Why does Thread FileDate give an error message?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37274/121) -- success

  ```
  autoThread[FileDate[FileNames["*", "C:\\Temp\\", 1]]]

    (* correct output *)
  ```
- [Efficient calculation of diagonal matrix elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45240/121) -- not applicable(?)
- [List operation list1 >= list2 should compare elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83236/121) -- success

  ```
   autoThread[{2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7} ~Max~ {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8}]
  ```

  > ```
  > {2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 8, 8}
  > ```
- [How to Thread with custom functions? Thread vs Map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85279/121) -- success

  ```
  autoThread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]
  ```

  > ```
  > {4, False, 12, 31}
  > ```

  ```
  x = {7, 8, 37, 127};

  autoThread[findPrime[x]]
  ```

  > ```
  > {4, False, 12, 31}
  > ```
- [Why doesn't Thread always thread?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102104/121) -- duplicate
- [Map works but Thread doesn't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108529/121) -- success

  ```
  autoThread @ D[{x, y}, {x, y}]
  ```

  > ```
  > {1, 1}
  > ```

  ```
  xy = {x, y};
  autoThread @ D[xy, xy]
  ```

  > ```
  > {1, 1}
  > ```
- [Function of Five Variables, and iterating over the last 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133028/121/#134188) -- not applicable
- [Thread Part ([[]]) over two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135909/121) -- success

  ```
  lst1 = {{5, -9, 15}, {12, -15, 4}};
  indices = {{2, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 2}};

  autoThread[Part[lst1, indices]]      (* no warning messages *)
  ```

  > ```
  > {{-9, 5, 15}, {12, 4, -15}}
  > ```
- [Inconsistent behavior of thread on empty llists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137227/121) -- success

  ```
  autoThread[f2[{}, 5]]
  ```

  > ```
  > {}
  > ```